# Stub super method in controller

Tags: rspec, super, stub

How to stub :super method from included module. I have following controller:

```
class ImportsController < BaseController
   include ImportBackend

  def import_from_file
    super
  rescue TransferPreview::Error => exc
    flash[:error] = "Some String"
    redirect_to imports_path
  end
end
```

And importBackend module:

```
module ImportBackend
  def import_from_file
    //something
  end
end
```

I want to test that controller. My question is how to stub method in ImportBackend to raise error? I tried couple solutions but nothing works:

```
ImportBackend.stub(:import_from_file).and_raise(Transfer::Error)
controller.stub(:super).and_raise(Transfer::Error)
controller.stub(:import_from_file).and_raise(Transfer::Error)
```

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in Ruby `super` looks like a method, but it's actually a keyword with special behavior (for example, `super` and `super()` do different things, unlike every other Ruby method), and you can't stub it.

What you really want to do is stub the method that `super` invokes, which in this case is `ImportBackend#import_from_file`. Since it's a mixin from a module (and not a superclass) you can't stub it in the usual way. You can, however, define a dummy module that has the mock behavior you want, and `include` it in your class. This works because when multiple modules define a mixin, `super` will invoke the last one included. You can [read more about this approach here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14547259/179125). In your case, it would look something like this:

```
mock_module = Module.new do
  def import_from_file
    raise Transfer::Error
  end
end

controller.singleton_class.send(:include, mock_module)
```

Depending on your other specs, this could introduce some complications with teardown, but I hope it helps get you started.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I would like to stub ImportBackend#import_from_file. I used your solution but test is failing still.

Comment: Sorry, @user2239655, I misread your question. I've updated my answer.